# Android capture image and video on Button click?

Tags: android

I want to open camera for image and video at a same time ,If i want to capature image than capture and discard it than i want to record video without going back .....is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In fact the default Android camera on every device do the same.
see this link . Here it has been clearly define how to implement this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html